# Getting the first empty cell value in a row

Tags: python, openpyxl

What I want to do is to find the first empty cells value in row 1 using openpyxl.
what i have tried is:

```
last_date = ws.max_column
x3 = ws.cell(row=1, column=last_date)
print(x3.value)
```

however this does not work because in my situation because i am looking for the first empty cell in row 1. This gets the last column that's data in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Above is what I’ve tried, but it’s wrong because it gets the last column that has data in it.